# Hyperlink of text suggestion

Tags: javascript, php, css, autocomplete

I have a auto complete input filed, I want to set hyperlink whenever we select suggested input. suggestion is working fine but i unable to make it hyperlink.

My code is given below :

```
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.autocomplete.css"> 

<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="auto1" name="category" >


<script>
var cat= [
    '<?php 
$blog_cat="select * from category order by cat_name asc";
$blog_query=mysql_query($blog_cat);
 while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($blog_query)){


     echo $data['cat_name'];
     echo "','";
 }?>',
];
$('#auto1').autocomplete({
    source:[cat]
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`source:[cat]` should be `source:cat`, you need to pass it an array, not an array of arrays.